# applyBinding () doesn't work if it is called only once

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm learning how to work with knockout.js and met some misunderstanding.

**UI:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>
            Caption:<span data-bind="text: object1.Caption" />
        </p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p>
            Manufacturer: <span data-bind="text: object1.Manufacturer" />
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
var viewModel = {
          object1: ko.observable()
     }

 $(document).ready(function () {  
   ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}
);

function getData ()
{
 var response = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        url:// my URL,
        success: function (data) {

            var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
            **//ko.applyBindings(viewModel);**

        }
    });
}
```

**JSON data:**

```
{"object1":{
  "Caption": "Some caption",
  "Manufacturer": "Some manufacturer"
}
}
```

It seems that I followed the tutorials, but if I try to call applyBindings(viewModel) only once on the start - it doesn't work. But it works if I call it every time in getData() function.

What is wrong? How to make it work using only one call of *applyBindings* on start ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the update overload of fromJS, and not re-assign it to viewModel:

```
success: function (data) {
    var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    ko.mapping.fromJS(result, viewModel);
}
```

In your case, you can also use the from JSON method, and save the call to jQuery:

```
success: function (data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJSON(data, viewModel);
}
```

You'll also need to have all the properties initialised when you first create the viewModel:

```
var viewModel = {
    object1: ko.observable(
    {
        "Caption": ko.observable(''),
        "Manufacturer": ko.observable('')
    })
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Paul. If I replace viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(result); with the line provided by you, nothing happens. Do I need to assign it the very first time somehow?

Comment: You need to still have the first applyBindings that you've got in your jQuery onload function. The only thing you need to change is the success method on your ajax call. I've updated the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I get correct result object which contains "object1" that consists of "Caption" and "Manufacturer" fields. There are no errors in browser debugger, but the list in UI is empty.

Comment: Ah, you might have to include the observable properties in object1 when you initialise the viewmodel for the first time. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

ko.mapping.fromJS returns a new object instance every time you call it. That's why you need to call applyBindings every time you fetch new data from the server.

If you want to just have a single of applyBindings you would need to have an ordinary ViewModel and update it's properties from the fetched data one by one or using some self implemented batch update method in your viewmodel.